# How to Subtract a Vector Path from a Rectangle in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

How does one subtract a vector path in Sketch. Shapes are straightforward and text is also doable. The white lines in the attached images need to be cuts through the rectangle so they are transparencies in the rectangle. Suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lines can't be subtracted. First convert them to a shape:
shift + command + O *or* layer > convert to outlines.

I see the arrow heads are already subtracted which might cause you a problem too. Try this:

- Undo the subtraction of the arrowheads
- Connect the (outlined!) lines with the arrowheads (use 'union')
- Subtract the connected lines and arrowheads with the rectangle.